# My component tree items do not show up on my design layout

Tags: android, android-layout, firebase, firebase-authentication

I wanted to create a **sign in activity XML** with Firebase and cannot seem to see any **textview** fields or **buttons** on the design layout? Is there something wrong with my code? I think there might be too many components in the Relative Layout? How can I minimize the components so they all fit?

```
< RelativeLayout xmlns: android = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns: app = "http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns: tools = "http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android: id = "@+id/main_layout"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "match_parent"
android: background = "@color/grey_100"
android: orientation = "vertical"
android: weightSum = "4" >

  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: layout_weight = "3"
android: gravity = "center_horizontal"
android: orientation = "vertical"
tools: ignore = "ObsoleteLayoutParam" >

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/icon"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.FirebaseIcon"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: contentDescription = "@string/desc_firebase_lockup"
android: src = "@drawable/firebase_lockup_400" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/title_text"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_marginBottom = "@dimen/title_bottom_margin"
android: text = "@string/emailpassword_title_text"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTitleText" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/status"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
android: text = "@string/signed_out" / >

  <
  TextView
android: id = "@+id/detail"
style = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyTextDetail"
tools: text = "Firebase User ID: 123456789abc" / >

  <
  /RelativeLayout>

  <
  ImageView
android: id = "@+id/imageView"
android: layout_width = "match_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
app: srcCompat = "@drawable/new_green_360"
tools: ignore = "ContentDescription" / >


  <
  RelativeLayout
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "0dp"
android: background = "@color/grey_300"
android: gravity = "center_vertical" >

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_email"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_email"
android: inputType = "textEmailAddress" / >

  <
  EditText
android: id = "@+id/field_password"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: hint = "@string/hint_password"
android: inputType = "textPassword" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/email_password_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_below = "@+id/email_password_fields"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_sign_in_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/sign_in"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
tools: ignore = "ButtonStyle" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/email_create_account_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1"
android: text = "@string/create_account"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
tools: ignore = "ButtonStyle" / >
  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  LinearLayout
android: id = "@+id/signed_in_buttons"
android: layout_width = "fill_parent"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_centerInParent = "true"
android: orientation = "horizontal"
android: paddingLeft = "16dp"
android: paddingRight = "16dp"
android: visibility = "gone"
android: weightSum = "2.0" >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/sign_out_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/sign_out"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
tools: ignore = "ButtonStyle" / >

  <
  Button
android: id = "@+id/verify_email_button"
android: layout_width = "0dp"
android: layout_height = "wrap_content"
android: layout_weight = "1.0"
android: text = "@string/verify_email"
android: theme = "@style/ThemeOverlay.MyDarkButton"
tools: ignore = "ButtonStyle" / >

  <
  /LinearLayout>

  <
  /RelativeLayout>

  <
  com.facebook.login.widget.LoginButton
android: id = "@+id/loginButton"
android: layout_width = "wrap_content"
android: layout_height = "18dp"
android: layout_alignParentBottom = "true"
android: layout_centerHorizontal = "true"
android: layout_marginBottom = "75dp"
android: paddingBottom = "10dp"
android: paddingTop = "10dp" / >

  <
  />
```

Comment: Please give me tips on how to set a bounty for this question.

Comment: there is no sufrfaceview in your XML. Why you expect anything to show on it, when you don't have it?

Comment: Please format your code decently. And remove the last `  <
  />`, which is useless and potentially harmful.

Comment: if you are adding the Surfaceview through code make sure u add it as first child

Comment: I've reformatted the question. It should be eaiser to understand now.